# z-index and stacking; removing a child from stacking context

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I'm trying to tweak the stacking order of some elements; here's an [SSCCE](http://jsfiddle.net/azYkb/8/).

Given this HTML snippet:

```
<div id="block1">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div id="widget">
        <div>Widgety goodness!</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="block2">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div id="block3">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to display `#widget` on top of `#block2`; which with the following CSS, you'll see is problematic without changing the location of `#widget` in the node tree.

```
#block1, #block2, #block3 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
#block1, #block3 {
    background-color: #abc;
    color: #123;
    z-index: 1;
}
#block2 {
    background-color: #def;
    color: #456;
    z-index: 2;
}
#widget {
    background-color: #f00;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 200px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

As you can see in the fiddle, `#widget` is overlapped partially by `#block2`; which makes perfect sense as the parent `#block1` is lower among siblings in the stacking order.

The obvious answer is: *make `#widget` a child of `#block2`*, but unfortunately that's not a solution here. Additionally, the `#blockN` elements cannot have their relative `z-index` values modified; blocks 1 and 3 must be lower than 2. (*by this I mean the calculated values could be different, but `#block2` will always be greater than it's siblings*). The reason for this, is `box-shadow` layering.

Is there any reasonable (*read: cross-browser, IE7+*) way to remove `#widget` from it's stacking context, while retaining it's position, coordinate location, dimensions, etc.?

Using `fixed` positioning removes it as desired, however it also obtains all the visual properties of being fixed (*which makes it a non-solution*)

<sub>I reckon this may have been answered in a roundabout way, however I didn't find it. Also, apologies; it appears I may have missed some innocuous but key details in my initial post. I think I've covered them all now.</sub>

Comment: +1 for a very clear description in the question

Comment: Thanks @AdityaSaxena, unfortunately I don't think I was clear enough; editing to clarify.

Comment: Ohh..is it ? I thought you wanted a cross-browser compatible solution without changing the location of #widget.

Comment: @AdityaSaxena Yea, but *also* without changing the z-indices of the blocks. The "middle" block will always have a `z-index` greater than it's siblings.

Comment: Can I ask why `widget` is a child of `block1`?

Comment: @DevlshOne Semantic flow and programmatic generation (*server-side*).

Comment: Are you willing to use some jQuery / JS to programmatically fix it?

Comment: @DevlshOne Well, perhaps (*if I gotta, I gotta*), however I was hoping to keep this a CSS-only solution.

Comment: Try this first! Make `#block2` `z-index:auto;`

Comment: @DevlshOne Unfortunately a no-go; as I mentioned the `z-index` of `#block2` must be higher than it's siblings. I've updated the fiddle link to demonstrate why (*note the `box-shadow`*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rules aren't really applying to the elements that you want them to be applied to. You need to explicitly set the z-index on the elements you want to position, in your case that element is the div child of block2. By simply modifying the first selector from:

```
#block1, #block2 , #block3 {
```

to

```
#block1, #block2 div, #block3 {
```

Your stacking order is corrected. Your z-index rules were being applied to the parents while the children continued to use the default of auto. In your case, by setting the position on #block2 div, you allow your widget to sit on top of the block2 child div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/azYkb/5/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, see the updated fiddle for reference as to why this won't work exactly (*note the `box-shadow`*)

Comment: Hmmm, then a JavaScript solution may be the only solution if you need to get that effect. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/azYkb/9/

Comment: Damn; I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. So basically it comes down to putting the `#widget` into `#block2` at some point (*whether generated server-side or moved via JS*) In summary, there ain't no way to get this to work visually with `#widget` as a child of `#block1`?

Comment: For your particular set of requirements it would appear that way.

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my question :-( Now it's a matter of deciding whether visual or semantic positioning are more important. I'm going to let it sit for a bit in case someone comes up with a workable solution (*or hack*) but if you wanna edit your answer to reflect these comments for future reference, I'll accept sometime later.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you do not need to change the location of the `#widget`. In my view, the answer lies in your question itself. [Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/azYkb/3/)

Edited CSS:

```
#block1{
    background-color: #abc;
    color: #123;
    z-index:3;
}

#block3 {
    background-color: #abc;
    color: #123;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A working solution is to make use of the `position` stacking order for the divs and not using z-index here. So no unwanted stacking-contexts are formed.

Block 1 & 3 get the default `position: static`

Block 2 gets `position: relative` (which is over 1 & 2)

and only the widget gets a z-index, which moves it on top of it all!

http://jsfiddle.net/4eENM/

Comment: Thanks! This is a great one-off solution. I'll keep it in mind for similar situations in the future, however I was hoping there'd be something that would work with explicit z-indices applied. Regardless, thanks again :-)

Comment: This will not yield the desired result if widget should be positioned relative to block 1. With this configuration widget might very well be positioned relative to the initial containing block. To see the difference set widget's top to 0 in both this answer's fiddle and the OP fiddle.